# Limit number of photos shown in jQuery Photowall

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the jQuery photowall plugin that can be found at http://creotiv.github.io/jquery-photowall/ .
Please view this to see descriptions and code. I am having some issues with long load times due to the large amount of photos that are in the Picassa web album it pulls from. To fix this issue I would like to be able to set a variable that could limit the number of photos pulled to x amount. If anyone could enlighten me on how this could be done I would appreciate it!

You can see the photowall implemented on a project of mine located here. http://hybridfuzionblackop.com/photos.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your http request to the Picasa API, you can specify a [`max-results` parameter](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#max-results). This is an example from their reference. I added the max-results parameter to the URL:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/118283508237214694671/albumid/5685978516288199793'
         +'/?alt=json&fields=entry(gphoto:id,title,media:group(media:thumbnail,media:'
         +'content))&imgmax=720&max-results=10',
  ...
});
```

(Note that I omitted the additional parameters).

Comment: Much better answer than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

I test it something like that:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/118283508237214694671/albumid/5685978516288199793'
             +'/?alt=json&fields=entry(gphoto:id,title,media:group(media:thumbnail,media:'
             +'content))&imgmax=720',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            var data2 = data.feed.entry.splice(0,10)
            console.log(data2);
        }
    });
```

This is shorter version of example. `data` is a json object which have entries for all images served from picassa. I used splice to get only first 10 images **but after download json data from picassa server**.

It's better download 1000 json objects than 1000 images.